# autoremove - permission issue

Tags: permissions

general difficulties with 16.04LTS
not able use many commands like the ones below

in an application with .conf file
the permission is root but i can not open it in gui environment.
is that normal, that the owner of most of the files is root and that they are inaccessible to the administrator ???

when i tried to install lighttpd, a websever even though i used sudo i get sys. msg. that i don't have root privileges.

i am so close to dumping the entire system but, without understand what is happening, its likely to occur again.
can someone explain how this develops or why it occurs ???

P.S. there is a known problem with the package lighttpd and the suggested solution is and people have had success using it but i can not get it to install.
`sudo apt-get install gamin`

```
admin@ubuntu_1604:/etc$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (30: Read-only file system)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.


this is just the beginning of a long sys. output
sudo apt-get update 

Ign:135 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:136 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (30: Read-only file system)
The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
Can't call method "policy" on an undefined value at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 56.
Reading package lists... Error!
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: The repository 'file:/.share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/ubuntu-hd/packages/xenial stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Symlinking file /.share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/ubuntu-hd/packages/xenial/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages to /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_.share_CACHEDEV1%5fDATA_.qpkg_ubuntu-hd_packages_xenial_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages failed - pkgAcqIndex::StageDownloadDone (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_dists_xenial_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease: Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
```

Comment: So many questions packed in there. Which one do you want us to answer?

Comment: `Read-only file system` is not really a permissions issue - it indicates that either you or the system has mounted the device in read-only mode (in the case of the system, that's likely because it has detected filesystem errors)

Comment: reply to user535733 i did not intend to ask such a broad list but tried to provide an overview of the problem which seem to be related. i am the only user and suddenly my system is not working. i have been trying to restore it through the forum suggestions that other have used but am not make progress. the latest attempt was  fsck -n -f   the sys. output was: fsck from util-linux 2.27.1 nothing else occurred. reply to steeldriver, i have not use the mounted command but thanks for the tip on filesystem errors. i will research that.